# Moving Ember Metal Views without re-rendering (drag and drop)

Tags: ember.js

We leverage the [draggable-each](https://github.com/krisselden/draggable-each) project to implement drag and drop functionality where we avoid re-rendering the moved views. I am trying to get this to work with Ember 1.9 and metal views. I have been trying to fix up the morphs without triggering a re-render of the child views. This works with dragging within one draggable-each view but not when dragging between them or inserting a new draggable-each. The views get re-rendered and I have yet to figure out why.

Could someone give some insight into how rendering is done in metal views and the best way to move views without triggering a re-rendering?

Thanks.

My current version is:

```
define('components/draggable-each', [], function () {

var a_slice = Array.prototype.slice;

var get = Ember.get;

return Ember.CollectionView.extend(Ember.TargetActionSupport, {
    classNames: ['ember-drag-list'],
    content: Ember.computed('context', function () {
        return this.get('context');
    }),
    handleSelector: null,
    itemSelector: '.draggable-item',
    target: Ember.computed.oneWay('controller'),
    init: function () {
        var itemView = this.get('itemView');
        var ItemViewClass;

        if (itemView) {
            ItemViewClass = this.container.lookupFactory('view:' + itemView);
        } else {
            ItemViewClass = this.get('itemViewClass');
        }

        this.set('itemViewClass', ItemViewClass.extend({
            context: Ember.computed.oneWay('content'),
            template: this.get('template'),
            classNames: ['draggable-item']
        }));

        this.updateRefCount = 0;

        this._super.apply(this, arguments);
    },

    nonVirtualChildViews: function () {
        var children = this._childViews;
        var nonVirtualChildren = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            var grandchildren = children[i].get('childViews');
            if (grandchildren) {
                for (var y = 0; y < grandchildren.length; y++) {
                    nonVirtualChildren.push(grandchildren[y]);
                }
            }
        }

        return nonVirtualChildren;
    },

    // lifted from Ember.Compontent
    sendAction: function (action) {
        var actionName;
        var contexts = a_slice.call(arguments, 1);

        // Send the default action
        if (action === undefined) {
            actionName = get(this, 'action');
        } else {
            actionName = get(this, action);
        }

        // If no action name for that action could be found, just abort.
        if (actionName === undefined) { return; }

        this.triggerAction({
            action: actionName,
            actionContext: contexts
        });
    },

    viewReceived: function (view /*, source */) {
        view.set('parentView', this);
        //view.set('parentView', this.get('parentView'));
        view.set('_parentView', this);
    },

    arrayWillChange: function () {
        if (this.updateDisabled()) { return; }
        this._super.apply(this, arguments);
    },

    arrayDidChange: function () {
        if (this.updateDisabled()) { return; }
        this._super.apply(this, arguments);
    },

    updateDisabled: function () {
        return this.updateRefCount > 0;
    },

    execWithoutRerender: function (func) {
        this.updateRefCount++;

        try {
            return func();
        } finally {
            this.updateRefCount--;
        }
    },

    // Note: entryView is optional--if not provided, view will render anew from entry
    //       skipNotify is also optional, and if not present, the itemWasInserted action will be sent
    // NOTE: make sure to call viewReceived outside of "updateDisabled" block if entryView already exists (i.e. is being moved from elsewhere)
    insertItem: function (index, entry, entryView, skipNotify, eventContext) {
        var list = this.get('context');
        if (entryView) {
            console.log('+++ adding view ' + entryView.get('elementId'));
        } else {
            console.log('+++ adding new view');
        }

        if (entryView) {
            //insert the view
            this._insertView(entryView, index);
            //update the DOM to reflect
            //index > 0 ? entryView.$().insertAfter(this._childViews[index - 1].$()) : this.$().prepend(entryView.$());
        }

        list.insertAt(index, entry);

        if (!skipNotify) {
            this.sendAction('itemWasInserted', entry, index, list, eventContext);
        }
    },

    // skipNotify is optional, and if not present, the itemWasInserted action will be sent
    removeItem: function (index, isDelete, skipNotify, eventContext) {
        var list = this.get('context');

        var object = list.objectAt(index);
        var entry = object.isController ? object.get('content') : object;
        var view = this._childViews[index];
        var elementId = view.get('elementId');

        console.log('--- removing view ' + elementId);

        //only remove from the childViews array once--if update is not disabled, then the view will be destroyed upon removing from the model,
        //and thus also removed from the views list... so if we remove here as well as in listeners, we might remove multiple views
        if (this.updateDisabled()) {
            this._removeView(view, index);
        }
/*
        if (!isDelete) {
            //if it is not a delete, we need to do a $().detach() to prevent data from being deferenced for GC
            view.$().detach();
        }
        else if (this.updateDisabled()) {
            view.remove();
        }
*/
        //remove from the backing array model, causing the view to be removed if update is not disabled
        list.removeAt(index);
        Ember.propertyDidChange(this, 'childViews');

        if (!skipNotify) {
            this.sendAction('itemWasRemoved', entry, index, list, eventContext);
        }

        return {
            entryModel: entry,
            entryView: view
        };
    },

    replaceItem: function (index, replacement, skipNotify, eventContext) {
        var list = this.get('context');

        var object = list.objectAt(index);
        var entry = object.isController ? object.get('content') : object;
        var view = this._childViews[index];

        //remove from the backing array model, causing the view to be removed if update is not disabled,
        //and add in the replacement at that same location
        list.replace(index, 1, [replacement]);

        if (!skipNotify) {
            this.sendAction('itemWasReplaced', entry, index, list, eventContext);
        }

        return {
            entryModel: entry,
            entryView: view
        };
    },

    moveItem: function (oldIndex, newIndex, source, eventContext) {
        var self = this;
        var sourceList = source.get('content');
        var targetList = this.get('content');

        var object = sourceList.objectAt(oldIndex);
        var entry = object.isController ? object.get('content') : object;
        //var viewToMove = source._childViews[oldIndex];
        //source._renderer.remove(view, false, true);
        //var view = source._childViews.splice(oldIndex, 1)[0];

        var doMove = function () {
            var viewToMove = source._childViews.splice(oldIndex, 1)[0];
            var resolvedNewIndex = newIndex + (self === source && oldIndex < newIndex ? -1 : 0);

            self._insertView(viewToMove, resolvedNewIndex);
            source._removeView(viewToMove, oldIndex);

            sourceList.removeAt(oldIndex);
            targetList.insertAt(resolvedNewIndex, entry);
            viewToMove.set('content', targetList.objectAt(resolvedNewIndex)); // needed when using item controllers that will get destroyed subsequent to the removeAt operation

            Ember.propertyDidChange(source, 'childViews');
            Ember.propertyDidChange(self, 'childViews');

            //var info = source.removeItem(oldIndex, false, true);
            //that.insertItem(resolvedNewIndex, info.entryModel, info.entryView, true);

            //return info;

            return {
                entryModel: entry,
                entryView: viewToMove
            };
        };

        var info = this.execWithoutRerender(function () {
            return source.execWithoutRerender(doMove, this);
        }, this);


        this.sendAction('itemWasMoved', info.entryModel, oldIndex, newIndex, source, eventContext);
    },

    // tell morph shadow DOM that child view should have this draggable-each as 
    // parent view now
    _insertView: function (view, newIndex) {
        //set the parentView of the new child
        this.viewReceived(view);
        view._morph = this._childViewsMorph.insert(newIndex, view.element);
        this._childViews.splice(newIndex, 0, view);
    },

    _removeView: function(view, index) {
        this._childViewsMorph.removeMorph(view._morph);
        this._childViews.splice(index, 1);
    }
});
});
```